# MySQL: copy information from table to another with opposite value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to copy information (boolean) from "details" table to "user" table as with "oppossite" value:

tables structure:
"user" table:

```
id     name     appear
1     John       null
2     Matt       null
3     jack       null
4     sara       null
5     sarah      null
```

"details" table:

```
id      user_id        appaer
1          1           false
2          2           false
3          3           true
4          4           true
5          5           true
```

result "user" table should look like;

```
id     name     appear
1     John       true
2     Matt       true
3     jack       false
4     sara       false
5     sarah      false
```

how to do this?

thanks,

Comment: case when appear=`true` then `false`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande can u provide full query pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update with `join and case-when`

```
update 
user u join details d on d.user_id = u.id 
set u.appear = case when d.appaer = 'true' then 'false' else 'true' end ;
```

Answer (score 1):

update appear from user table when `true` then `false` and join that two tables with `user_id`

```
update user
set appear=(select case when details.appear='true' then 'false'
                        when details.appear='false' then 'true' end
from details join user
on details.user_id=users.id)
```

Comment: also when 'false' then 'true' ? in two ways

Answer (score 0):

You could [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) *details* and *users* tables, use [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) on *user* table and use [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to change *true* to *false*

```
UPDATE user
SET appear = (
             SELECT CASE WHEN d.appear = 'true' THEN 'false' 
                         WHEN d.appear = 'false' THEN 'true' 
                    END
             FROM details d 
             JOIN users u
             ON d.user_id = u.id
             )
```